# How can I assign part of a string to a variable in C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve homework and I'm stuck in this problem because I'm used to Python, not C.

I want a piece of code that can put the last 2 chars in a word to a variable.

For example

```
Word: Hello
newVar = "lo"

Word: Sorry
newVar = "ry"
```

Please keep it simple, and if you wanna use something please try to explain it.

Comment: `newVar = Word + 3;`, maybe? Or perhaps `newVer = Word + strlen(Word)-2;`. A [mcve] would help.

Comment: @The Prince Provide a minimal code that shows what you are trying to do. For example how words are defined.

Comment: @Fred Larson, I tried it before I posted the question, and unfortunately didn't work. I keep getting an error

Comment: No way to tell why it failed without a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets create the string for you:

```
char word[] = "Hello";
```

If we "draw" the string how it looks like in memory it will be like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Now to get the end of the string, the last `'l'` and `'o'` we can simply create a pointer to the last `'l'`:

```
char *pointer_to_last_l = &word[3];
```

This pointer can be used as any other null-terminated string:

```
printf("end of string is %s\n", pointer_to_last_l);
```

If you really need to make a copy, then create a new array and use `strcpy` to copy from the character you want.

---

A "string" in C is nothing more than a sequence of characters, terminated by the special *null* character (not to be confused with a null pointer).

When you pass a string to a function, what you really pass is a pointer to the first character in such a sequence. Typically this is a pointer to the first character in an array.

**But** there is nothing to say that the pointer must be to the first character in the array. If we take the `printf` call from above:

```
printf("end of string is %s\n", pointer_to_last_l);
```

The variable `pointer_to_last_l` is pointing to the *fourth* character in the array. So the `printf` function will think that the string you pass is only `"lo"`.

So to copu this sub-string to a new array that's the pointer you use as source:

```
char new_word[8];  // Enough space for a small string
strcpy(new_word, &word[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Really means a lot to me. So basically what you saying is, all I need to do is to point to the word's strlen - 2 so I can point to 'L' in "HELLO" right?

Comment: @ThePrince but remember if you change the variale 'word` to for example "12345" the pointer point to `"45"` instead

Comment: Yes, I know but I really don't know how to use the pointer with strcpy:( can you provide a piece of code that can help?

Comment: I understood all that you said, yet I still can't write the code @Some programmer dude

Comment: @ThePrince  Added more explanation and example. The example should have been easy to figure out from the shown call to `printf`, if you just thought about it a little. Please try to think a little more next time, and experiment and try things yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *copyLastTwo(char *buff, const char *str)
{
    if(buff && str)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        len = len < 2 ? 0 : len - 2;
        strcpy(buff, str + len);
    }
    return buff;
}

int main(void)
{
    char newvar[3];

    copyLastTwo(newvar, "Hello");

    printf("Last two: %s\n", newvar);
}
```

Comment: First thing, Thanks for the effort! I'll try to understand what you did, because some stuff you wrote still unclear to me